# IIS Flask Server: IPython- ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached

Tags: python, flask, iis

I have deployed Flask Server on IIS. I'm getting below error while importing IPython module in my code.

I have tried `IPython` version: `5.0, 6.0, 7.16.3` but still

When i run my code through cmd it works and server on localhost starts. But when hosted through IIS Server below issue remains If I keep `import IPython` line in code.

My python config:

```
python 3.6

Flask==1.1.2
Keras==2.1.3
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scipy==1.4.1
tensorflow==1.14.0
wfastcgi==3.0.0
```

Heres my code:

```
from flask import Flask
import IPython

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/flaskapi2/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from FastCGI via IIS!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Error:

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
    env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler
    handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler
    handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]])
  File ".\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import IPython
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\venv36\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\venv36\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 15, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\venv36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 63, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import io
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\venv36\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 94, in <module>
    stdin = IOStream(sys.stdin, fallback=devnull)
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\venv36\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 38, in __init__
    for meth in filter(clone, dir(stream)):
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\venv36\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 37, in clone
    return not hasattr(self, meth) and not meth.startswith('_')
  File "E:\deploy_car_damage\venv36\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 81, in closed
    return self.stream.closed
ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

What does `underlying buffer has been detached` mean and how can I resolve it.

Comment: IPython is known to be incompatible with wfastcgi (interactive shell vs. FastCGI with stdin/stdout. Did you try to use HttpPlatformHandler? https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: could you please try reinstalling the python and fast CGI on your machine? after that follow these steps to add python fast CGI app on iis: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423045/unknown-fastcgi-error-occurred-python-web-api/63447326#63447326